Display image from flask view to html
I want to diplay an image send from flask view to html. Below is what i have tried so far.
app.py
# Route to show processed files
@app.route('/view_process', methods=['POST', 'GET'] ,endpoint='view_process')
def process_files():

    file_names = []

    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return redirect(url_for('login_user'))

    csvs,imagenames = inference.main()
    #imagenames returns the path of the image ['./outputs/image10']

    for file in csvs:
        file_names.append(os.path.basename(file))
 
    #subprocess.run(['python', 'inference.py'],capture_output=True, text=True)

    return render_template('view_process.html', message='Files processed sucessfully. Click to           Download', csvs = csvs, file_names=file_names,imagenames=imagenames)


# Route for image
@app.route('/sendimage/<path:image>',methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def send_image(image):
    return send_file(image,as_attachment=True)


view_process.html
{% for file in csvs %}
        {% for filename in file_names %}
            {% for imagename in imagenames %}
                <a href="{{ url_for('download_file', filename=file) }}">  {{ filename }}</a>

                <img src="{{ url_for('send_image', image=imagename) }}" alt="My Image">

                {% endfor %}
         {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

What i get is an empty object What im doing wrong?

To display an Image on the browswer. That attachement should not be True.
Try sending the file with disabled attachment.
# Route for image
@app.route('/sendimage/<path:image>',methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def send_image(image):
    return send_file(image,as_attachment=False)


